# Sparsity of DFT of powers of random sequence

Tags: random, fourier-transform, sparsity

Given a randomly chosen finite sequence of complex values ($a_0,a_1 \dots a_{N-1}$) such that their DFT is sparse, can anything be said about the sparsity of the DFT of the sequences ($a_0^{\frac{k}{N}}, a_1^{\frac{k}{N}} \dots a_{N-1}^{\frac{k}{N}}$) for $k : (1,2 \dots N-1$)? Is my intuition right in saying that the sequences would have a high probability of having sparse DFT?

Comment: Multiplication becomes convolution. So I would guess it depends on the pattern of sparsity.

Comment: @mathreadler In that case, averaging over all k-sparse patterns, can any conclusions be drawn about the generated sequences?

Comment: What is a k-sparse pattern? One non-zero element every k:th element in the DFT space?

Comment: @mathreadler No, I meant $k$ random indices are chosen (from the $N$) and randomly generated values are assigned to them (this would be the $k$-sparse DFT of the sequence ($a_0,a_1 \dots a_{N-1}$))

Comment: Okay, then it would depend on the least common multiple of gap sizes. If gaps end up relatively prime it will in general become dense. Another special case is if we have multiples of $m$ gap size then it will be a power function applied to a periodic function which of course will remain a periodic function of the same period.

Comment: @mathreadler But, is your argument reversible? Given the sequence $\{a_i\}$ and looking at its ($2,3 \dots N-1$) powers, you are correct. Given the sequence for the highest power ($N/N$), would your argument hold for the lower powers ($k/N$)?

Comment: You must first pick a branch for the power function which you then can consider a power series expansion for. A power series expansion is a sum of iterated multiplications which by linearity of the transform become a linear combination of the same kind of iterated self-convolutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65380/discussion-between-nived-rajaraman-and-mathreadler).